# Unable to run index.html locally using nginx

Tags: nginx

I have configuration setup as below.

**nginx.config**
I have included `include conf.d/*.conf;` at bottom of the file.

**demoSite.config**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.local.com;

    location / {
        root   /Users/nikhilwali/Documents/Project/threejs_Demo/;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        return 204;
        access_log     off;
        log_not_found  off;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

**host**

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 

127.0.0.1   dev.local.com
```

Still when I run `sudo nginx`

`Error: 403 Forbidden`

Comment: do you have any nginx syntax errors from `nginx -t`?

Comment: No syntax error in the log